# Column sort an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to column-sort a multi-dimensional array. I have the code setup, but it's not displaying the right results...

Example before sorting:

6.0  4.0 2.0

4.0  2.0  4.0

1.0  3.0  1.0

Example after sorting:

1.0 2.0 1.0

4.0 3.0 2.0

6.0 4.0 4.0

This is my code:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ColumnSorting
    {
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     run();
   }
   public static void run()
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter the values of your 3x3 matrix: ");
      double[][] matrix = new double[3][3];
      for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
      {
         for (int k = 0; k < matrix[i].length; k++)
         {
            matrix[i][k] = input.nextDouble();
         }
      }
      printArrays(matrix);

    }
   public static void printArrays(double[][] matrix)
   {
   System.out.println("Before sorting: ");

       for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
      {
        for (int k = 0; k <matrix[i].length; k++)
         {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][k] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
    double[][] newMatrix = sortColumns(matrix);
     System.out.println();
    System.out.println("After sorting: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < newMatrix.length; i++)
      {
         for (int j =0; j < newMatrix[i].length; j++)
         {
            System.out.print(newMatrix[i][j] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }  

   }
   public static double[][] sortColumns(double[][] m)
   {
      double min;
      double temp;
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
         min = m[0][i];
         for (int k = 0; k < m.length; k++)
         {

            if (min > m[k][i])
            {
               temp = min;
               m[0][i] = m[k][i];
               m[k][i] = temp;
            }
         }
      }
      return m;

   }
}
```

This is what i'm getting:

1.0 3.0 1.0

6.0 4.0 4.0

6.0 4.0 2.0

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort algorithm is not sorting - it is doing something strange.

Here's a bubble-sort equivalent for demonstration.

```
public static double[][] sortColumns(double[][] m) {
    for (int col = 0; col < m[0].length; col++) {
        // Have we swapped one on this pass?
        boolean swapped;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for (int row = 0; row < m.length - 1; row++) {
                // Should these be swapped?
                if (m[row][col] > m[row + 1][col]) {
                    // Swap this one with the next.
                    double temp = m[row][col];
                    m[row][col] = m[row + 1][col];
                    m[row + 1][col] = temp;
                    // We swapped! Remember to run through again.
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        } while (swapped);
    }
    return m;

}
```

Although a better option would be to copy each column out to a separate array, sort it and put it back in - at least that way you would not be needing to implement your own sorting algorithm.

```
public static double[][] sortColumnsProperly(double[][] m) {
    // Sort each colum.
    for (int col = 0; col < m[0].length; col++) {
        // Pull the column out.
        double[] thisCol = new double[m.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            thisCol[i] = m[i][col];
        }
        // Sort it.
        Arrays.sort(thisCol);
        // Push it back in.
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            m[i][col] = thisCol[i];
        }
    }
    return m;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I knocked up an example of yout problem, hope it helps.

**Code**

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[][] m = new double[4][4];

        m[0][0] = 6.4;
        m[0][1] = 4.0;
        m[0][2] = 2.0;

        m[1][0] = 4.0;
        m[1][1] = 2.0;
        m[1][2] = 4.0;

        m[2][0] = 1.0;
        m[2][1] = 3.0;
        m[2][2] = 1.0;

        System.out.println("---Before sort---");
        printSort(m);

        double[][] x = matrixColumnSort(m);

        System.out.println("---After sort---");
        printSort(x);
    }

    public static double[][] matrixColumnSort(double[][] m) {

        ArrayList<Double> arrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.length - 1; j++) {
                arrayList.add(m[j][i]);
            }
            Collections.sort(arrayList);
            for (int j = 0; j < m.length - 1; j++) {
                m[j][i] = arrayList.get(j);
            }
            arrayList.clear();
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static void printSort(double[][] m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.length - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + m[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
---Before sort---
 6.4  4.0  2.0 
 4.0  2.0  4.0 
 1.0  3.0  1.0 
---After sort---
 1.0  2.0  1.0 
 4.0  3.0  2.0 
 6.4  4.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting algorithm is wrong for different reasons : you don't update `min` when you find a new one, you are comparing each element only to the minimum value when it should be compared to all elements...

I can suggest 2 solutions :

1. look at existing algorithms to sort arrays
2. transpose the matrix, use `Arrays.sort()` on lines, transpose the
   matrix back